# Singular Points and their Classification

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Suppose I have these functions:

1. $\frac{1}{z-z^3}$
2. $\frac{1}{(z^2+4)^2}$
3. $\frac{e^z}{1+z^2}$

I need to find the singular points of these functions, and classify them ($\infty$ included). So far, I understand that finding the singular points themselves is as simple as setting the denominator to be $0$. However, I do not comprehend at all how to classify them.

Either way, I decided to try something to see where it'd lead me. For the first function, the singular points are at $z = -1, z = 0, z = 1$, because the function can be rewritten as

$$ \frac{1}{z(1-z^2)}$$

I was told that if the limit is infinite for the singular point in question, then that point is a pole. How do I determine which order of a pole it is? Also, I was told that I could also expand these in a Laurent series and find the principal part, but I fail to see how that would help me (and I believe it would take too long anyways).

Any suggestions/comments? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are three kinds of singularities:
 1. Removable Singularity 
 2. Poles
 3. Essential Singularity

**The Limit Way of Classification**:

A function $f$ which is holomorphic for all $z$ near $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ (with $z \neq z_0$) has a pole of order $m>0$ at $z=z_0$ if and only if

$$
\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)^m f(z)
$$

is finite and nonzero.

If $f$ has a singularity at $z=z_0$ and

$$
\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z)
$$

is finite and nonzero then the singularity is removable, and vice versa.

If the singularity is not of the above kinds, then it is essential.

**Laurent Series Method**

Personally, I think this is easier in most cases and doesn't take that long.

Once you expand your function in its Laurent Series form, a simple analysis of the principal part - that is the part where the ($z$ - $z_0$) occurs in the denominator - will give away the answer.

If there are no terms in the principal part, then your singularity is removable. 
Finitely many terms mean it is a pole. 
The greatest order m such that ($z - z_0)^m$ is in the denominator - is the order of the pole. If it is 1, then it's known as a simple pole.

If there are infinite such terms, then the singularity is essential.

Hope this helps.

Example for Laurent Series Usage :

$f(z)$ = $\frac{1}{z-z^3}$ = $\frac{1}{z(1-z^2)}$ = $\frac{1}{z}$$(1+z^2+z^4+...)$

(We've used $\frac{1}{z}$ = $1+z+z^2+..$ for $z^2$ )

= $\frac{1}{z}$ + $z+z^3+..$

Here, the principal value is just $\frac{1}{z}$. Therefore, this singularity is a pole of order 1.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how using a Laurent series would be useful? I'm still not sure how to interpret (much or less find) the principal part.

Comment: I have edited the post with an elaborate example. Does this help?

Comment: I understand how you got $\frac{1}{z} + z + z^3 + ...$, but I do not understand how you concluded that $\frac{1}{z} $ is the principal value.

Comment: @K.M. The principle part of the series is all of the terms that have a $z$ in the denominator.

Comment: Ok, now this all makes sense. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @SukanyaMukherjee, so  for $f(z) = \frac{1}{z-z^{3}}$, $z = -1$ and $z = 1$ are also poles of order $m = 1$ b/c $\lim_{z \to z_{0}} (z-z_{0})^{m}f(z)$ in both of those cases is finite and zero? 

Also, how can you tell whether any of the functions he gave above have singularities at $\infty$?

Comment: @SukanyaMukherjee, I found that the third function has an essential singularity at $\infty$. What about 1 and 2 - do they have singularities at $\infty$? I think they have removable singularities there, b/c $\lim_{z \to 0}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = 0$ for both. Since the limits are finite, $0$ is a removable singularity of $f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$; therefore $\infty$ is a removable singularity of $f(z)$ in each case. Is this right?

Comment: @wgrenard, if you can answer the questions I posed in my last two comments, please feel free to do so.

Comment: @Jessy Cat, how did you determine that function 3 has $\infty$ as an essential singularity? If you take the limit approaching that value, you get $\infty$, but this means this is a pole of some order.

Comment: @K.M., If you take the limit of $f(1/z)$ as $z \to 0$, you get different values depending on how you approach the origin. If you approach it along the negative real axis, you get $0$, and if you approach it along the positive real axis, you get $\infty$. Since the value of the limit is path dependent, the limit d.n.e., which implies that $z = 0$ is an essential singularity of $f(1/z)$, which implies that $z = \infty$ is an essential singularity of $f(z)$.